# how to implement a authentication with spring boot security?

Tags: spring-boot

i am using spring boot.  i want to post a username and password params to login, and if login success then return a token. after, i will use the token to judge login status. here is my security configure code. but i don't konw where to write the login authentication logic code.

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user/unlogin")
                .permitAll(); 
     }

     @Override
     public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         web.ignoring().antMatchers("/user/login")
                .antMatchers("/user/logout")
                .antMatchers("/user/register"); 
     }
}
```

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's always more than one way to do something with Spring. There is a happy path (probably) with Spring Boot, and you seem to have started on it. Note though, if you want Boot to provide some default behaviour, then don't use `@EnableWebSecurity` (as advised in the user guide). The [web-secure sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure) has an example you can follow.

If you use `formLogin()` the default login URL is `/login` (not `/user/login`), so you should be able to post the username and password to that endpoint to authenticate. Don't add `/login` to the unsecured paths using `web.ignoring()` or Spring Security will never process it. When you post to `/login` you get back a `JSESSIONID` cookie. That's your authentication token, and it expires when the session expires in the server (30min by default, but easily configurable). Include it in future requests for secure resources - some HTTP clients will even do that for you (like a browser does).